# quasilinear utility maximization with non-negativity constraints

Tags: utility

I have a utility function:
max $U = \frac{c_o^{1-\eta}}{1-\eta} + \frac{\beta}{2} c_{1a} + \frac{\beta}{2} c_{1b} $
subject to the budget constraint $p_0c_0 + p_{1a}c_{1a} + p_{1b}c_{1b} = p_0e_0 + p_{1a}e_{1a} + p_{1b}e_{1b} = p_0 + p_{1a}(1+\epsilon) + p_{1b}(1-\epsilon)   $ and the non-negativity constraints for $c_{1a},c_{1b}$

How do I solve for the optimal solution $(c_0,c_{1a},c_{1b})$?

I try to set up a Lagrangian for this and divide it by cases:
$L = \frac{c_o^{1-\eta}}{1-\eta} + \frac{\beta}{2} c_{1a} + \frac{\beta}{2} c_{1b} + \theta_1(p_0c_0 + p_{1a}c_{1a} + p_{1b}c_{1b} - p_0 - p_{1a}(1+\epsilon) - p_{1b}(1-\epsilon)) + \theta_2c_{1a} + \theta_3c_{1b}$

The FOCs are:
$$ c_o^{-\eta} -\theta_1p_0 = 0 $$
$$ \frac{\beta}{2} - \theta_1 p_{1a} + \theta_2 = 0 $$
$$ \frac{\beta}{2} - \theta_1 p_{1b} + \theta_3 = 0 $$
$$ p_0c_0 + p_{1a}c_{1a} + p_{1b}c_{1b} = p_0 + p_{1a}(1+\epsilon) + p_{1b}(1-\epsilon)  $$

1. For corner solution cases, i.e, $c_{1a} = 0, c_{1b} > 0, \theta_3 = 0$, I can find a solution, but for interior solution case, i.e, $c_{1a} > 0, c_{1a} > 0, \theta_2 = 0, \theta_3 = 0$, I cannot proceed because only the budget constraint has $c_{1a},c_{1b}$ so I cannot find both.
2. Even if I can find all three cases (2 corner solutions, 1 interior solution), how do I know which solution is optimal?

Comment: Is this the first utility optimization problem you encounter? Have you by any chance ever had a problem where the goal/utility function was one of perfect complements? If yes, did you solve it by Lagrangian?

Comment: For 1: $c_{1a}$ and $c_{1b}$ are perfect substitutes. There are infinite solutions if their prices are equal. For 2: for each price, there's only one case. If $p_{1a}=p_{2a}$ you have interior solution. If $p_{1a}>p_{2a}$ you have $c_{1a}=0$, if $p_{1a}<p_{2a}$ you have $c_{2a}=0$.

Comment: Also, for the interior solution, the consumer is indifferent on any combination of $c_{1a}$ and $c_{1b}$, including the combinations where one of them is zero.